# hub_verify_index and hub_challenge error in Messenger Bot

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I'm try to build messenger bot with PHP by following these two guides: http://blog.adnansiddiqi.me/develop-your-first-facebook-messenger-bot-in-php/ and https://medium.com/@nadeem.manzoor0/facebook-messenger-platform-web-hook-setup-in-php-893ead06746b#.lcpp0jh9o.

And I used `nGrok v2.1.18` to work my `localhost` code from messenger bot. In my `localhost`, I already installed `xampp control panel v3.2.1`.

Here is my `webhook.php`:

```
<?php
/* validate verify token needed for setting up web hook */ 
if (isset($_GET['hub_verify_token'])) { 
   if ($_GET['hub_verify_token'] === 'here_is_my_token') {
       echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
       return;
   } else {
       echo 'Invalid Verify Token';
       return;
   }
} else {
   echo $_GET['hub_verify_token'];
   echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

/**
 * Some Basic rules to validate incoming messages
 */
if(preg_match('[time|current time|now]', strtolower($message))) {

    // Make request to Time API
    ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');
    $result = file_get_contents("http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?format=%25a%20%25b%20%25d%20%25I:%25M:%25S%20%25Y");
    if($result != '') {
        $message_to_reply = $result;
    }
} else {
    $message_to_reply = 'Huh! what do you mean?';
}
print $message_to_reply;
//API Url
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<my-token>';


//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
        "id":"'.$sender.'"
    },
    "message":{
        "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'"
    }
}';

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = $jsonData;

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

//Execute the request
if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])){
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
?>
```

And I already set webhooks url in my facebook app page like this: `https://903....ngrok.io/FunBot/webhook.php` and also set verify token. There is no problem.

When I send message from my page, I can see reply in `nGrok` with `200 OK`. But in the messeger bot, it doesn't reply anything.

So, I try to log from `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)` and there is no error.

But I got `"Undefined index: hub_challenge in C:\xampp\htdocs\FunBot\webhook.php on line ....."` and `"Undefined index: hub_verify_token in ......."` error, when I try to print `$_GET['hub_verify_token']` and `$_GET['hub_challenge']`.

Here is the `undefined index` error result on `nGrok`.
[image: undefine index result image]

I'm not sure these two `"undefined index"` problem may cause the bot not reply.

And should I need to change `me/messages?` from `$url` to `page id` or some others id.

I already read a lot of posts on `stackoverflow` about bot not reply problem and it doesn't work for me. I don't really know which part is wrong because this is first time for me with bot.

I'm very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: Don’t remove line numbers from error messages! You are only using `$_GET['hub_verify_token']` at the top of this script, and it is wrapped in an `isset` statement - so it is rather impossible that you get the error `Undefined index: hub_verify_token` with that code.

Comment: @CBroe I mean is when I just try to echo without checking with `isset()`, I got those `undefined index` error. I think its not deserved with down vote.

Comment: @CBroe I already updated my question. Can you please check me again?

Comment: Trying to output the content of a variable that isn’t set makes no sense.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your point. Can you please suggest how can I fix my problem?

Comment: What problem? If a variable is not set, then don’t try to output it …

Comment: I mean bot doesn't reply problem.

Comment: Are you done with the setup part already? And I hope you are not working on external tutorials only, but have also consulted the official documentation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126780/discussion-between-cloud-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. The main problem is `SSL` problem. Without using `SSL` certificate, bot doesn't reply anything even the code is fine. And I don't have `SSL`. So, I stuck in strange problem.

So, now I used [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to upload my code repository and set up webhooks again with url from `Heroku`. By using `Heroku`, you don't need to worry about `SSL`. Now, everything is fine.

This [link](https://cli.traan.vn/how-to-create-a-facebook-bot-in-10-minutes-the-complete-tutorial-from-zero-to-hero-ku-352dca274046#.ants2vszm) is very helpful to create messenger bot.

I hope my answer can help for someone.

Comment: I my case I'm using Ipage host there is an option on admin panel called secure server which allows you to get free ssl linke to any file